# How to convert the nvarchar record to date format in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which one of the column is setup as nvarchar. This column is called bestBefore. So this is giving us trouble now, I am planning to change the column type to datetime, but before that, there are corrupt record as shown below :

```
'Mon Feb 19 23:45:59 EST 2018'
'2017-12-11 20:55:47.831'
'Mon Dec 18 18:51:54 EST 2017'
```

The second row is what I expect it to my new record should look like.
So I wrote something like this :-

```
select top 1000 CONVERT(datetime, bestBefore, 103) from 
[dbo].[TestTable] order by id desc
```

However I got this error -'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Can someone help me? If I can convert correctly, then I might able to change the column type.

Comment: From a quick glance at the convert docs, I'm not sure that these timestamps can be directly converted.  Is there any chance that you could scrub this data before bringing it into SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think I can do that, is it possible if i use whereclause to convert, i am trying to fix it fast.

Comment: It's not that the column is *corrupt*, it's just that it's *inconsistent*, and that's an inherent problem with storing date/time values as text. If you can't force the upstream provider to be *consistent* then you'll have to devise an import layer that can accommodate all of the possible variants. Good luck.

Comment: @GordThompson what do you mean?

Comment: what version of sql server? 2012 or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that SQL Server directly supports the following format mask:

```
Mon Feb 19 23:45:59 EST 2018
```

But we can still piece together a date format which is supported.  The above timestamp with the 109 format mask would appear as follows:

```
Feb 19 2018 23:45:59
```

Consider the following query:

```
-- replace the yourTable CTE with your actual table
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'Mon Feb 19 23:45:59 EST 2018' AS col
),
cte AS (
    SELECT
        col,
        new_col,   -- a new datetime column
        CONVERT(datetime,
            SUBSTRING(col, 5, 3) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(col, 9, 2) + ' ' +
            RIGHT(col, 4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(col, 12, 8), 109) AS col_out
    FROM yourTable
)

    col                             col_out
1   Mon Feb 19 23:45:59 EST 2018    19.02.2018 23:45:59
```

### Demo

To update, just use the following:

```
UPDATE cte
SET new_col = col_out;
```

Comment: Hey thank you, from here, can we do the update @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal I tried to edit my answer per your new requirements.

Comment: Alright but I was having the Incorrect Syntax, so I am checking no @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Is there anything I missed here? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Did you create a new datetime column?

Comment: I got it sir, but just now I saw I still have this kind of format 'Oct 10 2017  2:07AM', is it possible if I use the same query?

Comment: it is still giving an incorrect syntax even when I remove the new_Col

Comment: I don't have your tables and data in front of me.  I have answered your original question which is about a date string conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Made some changes from @Tim Biegeleisen's answer.

```
DECLARE @bestBefore VARCHAR(50)='2017-12-11 20:55:47.831'

IF((SELECT LEFT(@bestBefore,1)) IN('S','M','T','W','F'))
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CONVERT(datetime,
            SUBSTRING(@bestBefore, 5, 3) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@bestBefore, 9, 2) + ' ' +
            RIGHT(@bestBefore, 4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@bestBefore, 12, 8), 109) AS col_out
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @bestBefore
END
```

Hope this helps.